# Cannot Import Asmx web service reference in vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, visual-studio-2008, asmx, vb.net-2010

I have web site built in visual studio 2008 using .net framework 3.5.Now i want to migrate the web site code to visual studio 2010 but want to keep the target framework to same i.e 3.5. The web site is built using vb.Net.MY problem is when i am importing the reference of web service in visual studio 2010  it show error as "NameSpace or type specified in imports 'WebReference' does not contain any public methods".My service name is "WebReference" . I thought may be .net has built in  System.web.services.Description.Webreference ,may be it shows conflict ,so i tried to rename it to "WebReference1" or some other name but it does not have any effect,yhe error is still there.What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

probably it is because you cannot use importer :

ServiceDescriptionImporter importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();

in vs 2010....you need vs 2012 because that only has support for .net framework 4.5 which in turn has assembly references to ServiceDescriptionImporter .